# What is the value of this supremum?

Tags: real-analysis

Define $A=\sup \limits_{f} \{m^*(f[0, 1])\}$, here $f$ are all the functions which satisfy that
$f: [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$; $\forall x, f(x)-x \in \mathbb{Q}; \forall x, y, x-y \in \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow f(x)=f(y)$.

What is the value of $A$? Obviously, $0<A \leq 1$.

Comment: $m^*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure, right?

Comment: Yes, it is the Lebesgue outer measure. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your conditions may be restated as: $f$ induces a choice function for the partition of $[0,1]$ defined by the equivalence $x\sim y$ iff $x-y\in \mathbb Q$. So the image of $f$ is a Vitali set (a choice of representatives for that partition). Therefore $A=1$ because there are Vitali set of outer measure $1$. Here are
constructions:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/vitali-type-set-with-given-outer-measure
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157532/vitali-set-of-outer-measure-exactly-1

Comment: Thanks for your answers.